# Changing NSAttributedString text value for a UIControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

Currently all my buttons and textfields have `attributedText` values defined to be attributed strings.

Consider the case with a simple `UILabel`. Whenever I have to change the text for this `UILabel` (based on some user action), I have to redefine the attributes on the `NSAttributedString`. One way is to simply create a subroutine that generates these attributes whenever I require them but that's a concern given there could be a number of different labels (or attributed strings) that would require such convenience methods.

Another could be simply changing the `text` field and having observers add those attributes but that's the same amount of work and now probably more complicated.

Is there a simple way of achieving the above without redefining attributes?

Comment: What about category?

Comment: I am not sure what you are implying. What about it?

Comment: You'll have to redefine your attributes each time, there is no way around it. I think what Harry was trying to say is that having a category on UILabel will avoid code duplication and allow you to expose convenience methods to update your attributed text for all the UILabel through your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploring @Harry's ideas, here are a few ideas :

Category on `NSAttributedString`, category on `UILabel`, or category on `NSDictionary`, and maybe a mix of them, according to which one best suits you and your project.
Using a category on `NSAttributedString` in priority before `UILabel` could be more interesting in case you wanted to use the custom `NSAttributedString` for others kind of object (like a `UITextView`).

A good start:

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    AttributeStyle1,
    AttributeStyle2,
} AttributeStyles;
```

A possible category method on `NSDictionary`:

```
-(NSDictionary *)attributesForStyle:(AttributeStyles)style
{
    NSDictionary *attributes;
    switch(style)
    {
        case AttributeStyle1:
            attributes = @{}//Set it
            break;
        case AttributeStyle2:
            attributes = @{}//Set it
            break;
        default:
            attributes = @{}//Set it
            break;
    }
    return attributes;
}
```

Category possible on `UILabel`:

```
-(void)setString:(NSString *)string withAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
{
    [self setAttributedText:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes];
}
```

Category possible on `NSAttributedString`:

```
-(NSAttributedString  *)initWithString:(NSString *)string withStyle:(AttributedStyles)style
{
    //Here, a mix is possible using the first method, or doing here the switch case
    //Ex:  return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:[NSDictionary attributesForStyle:style];
    //And to use like this: [yourLabel setAttributedText:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string withStyle:AttributeStyle1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually explored all of these options. The only issue is that there are different types of labels/textfields; i.e. they require different fonts, etc; I guess I could include this in the setter and initializer as well. Fair enough!